# Killed Ostrava as a Black Phantom but can't loot him

Tags: demons-souls

In Demon Souls, right before you fight Old King Allant, I had to fight Ostrava. He was in Black Phantom form. When I dealt my final blow, it pushed him onto the brick wall banister of the staircase and that is where the loot is on top of.

Unfortunately, it's impossible to get on there. Is there any way I can get the loot, i.e. Go to Nexus, reload save? He's the only way to get the Mausoleum key until NG+ and I really don't want to have to wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Black Phantom form of Ostrava doesn't drop the Mausoleum key, he drops the [Rune Sword and Rune Shield](http://demonssouls.wikidot.com/bp-rune-sword). You can get both of these items relatively easily [in level 3-2](http://demonssouls.wikidot.com/rune-sword), so don't worry about losing the loot you're having trouble with.

The Mausoleum Key (according to [here](http://demonssouls.wikidot.com/mausoleum-key)) you get from Ostrava as a gift in 1-4 after you speak to him (presumably in human form), if he hasn't died before then.

Comment: What if I already killed the dark phantom, I didn't find him as a human ..